# Opposite of Over-Allocated

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm trying to find a short word or 2 to mean the opposite of over-allocated, the shorter the better. "Allocated Correctly" doesn't really mean the same thing and "Not Over-Allocated" seem a bit awkward with the double negative.

I'd like to create a list of people with a tick or cross like the pic below.

[image]

**Edit:** Just to clarify, this particular meaning is referring to "*has not been over allocated*", rather than "*has some remaining capacity to allocate*".

Comment: _underallocated_?

Comment: "Underutilized" or "Without Overtime" perhaps.  They have fewer hours than they would like, perhaps.  Anyway, hours are not allocated; they're worked.  In some industries (e.g., trucker, airline pilot) there's a limit on permitted hours by government regulation or union rules.

Comment: @NVZ sorry mate. I was originally going to include the info but didn't think it would add much use to anyone. I had tried to search online thesauruses. But they don't seem very good for prefixed words. Found plenty of definitions, but no synonyms or antonyms. If you want an exact record of my search you can check out all 10 entries on the first page here: https://www.google.com.au/#safe=off&q=overallocation+antonym

Comment: @Xanne "Without Overtime" is definitely more correct for this scenario than underutilized or underallocated.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're talking about; are Joe, Bob, and Mary people, or are they machines?  Do they get paid more after a certain number of hours?  This is just a guessing game.

Comment: From a UI standpoint I would say to call the column "Over-Allocated", put a red checkmark in the box where too many hours are assigned, and leave the box empty where the number of hours is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a phrase such as "**within capacity**" or "**allocated appropriately**" gets at what you're trying to communicate (i.e. that the person is not taxed beyond what he or she can handle).

Comment: Allocated Appropriately is an accurate description